# отправка из одной form на два обработчика

Tags: php, header

Доброе время суток!
Есть form, если валидация успешна, отправляю c помощью session массив с данными через header на обработку для получения pdf файла, либо для получения Exel файла.
Как организовать в одном коде отправку для создания обоих файлов условно "одновременно". 
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#youform').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    //...
  });
  $.ajax({
    ///
  });
});
```

если по-человечьи, то вешайте на событие submit свой обработчик, и двумя асинхронными аяксами шлите запросы. ключевое слово здесь - **асинхронными**, что означает, что сначала скрипт отправит первый запрос, потом (не дожидаясь ответа) сразу второй... а потом, по прибытии каждого из файлов, вызовет разные коллбэки, которые вы укажете. Подробнее - см. доки по jQuery.ajax();